# Edit schedule based on foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, date, schedule

I want to create date schedule for an attandance system with PHP.
So I have : 
Table `SCHEDULE`

```
id | room | day | class_id
1  | 11   | Mon | 2
3  | 12   | Tue | 3
5  | 11   | Mon | 4
```

Table `MEETING`

```
id | date        | time | schedule_id
1  | 06 Oct 2014 | 9:00 | 1
2  | 13 Oct 2014 | 9:00 | 1
3  | 20 Oct 2014 | 9:00 | 1
```

So meeting records were generated based on `SCHEDULE` record, in this example, `MEETING id: 1,2,3` is based on `SCHEDULE id: 1` that generate every monday till x weeks.

So the PROBLEM is : IF I edit column `DAY` from `SCHEDULE`, how can I update the date column ?
Ie : I update `SCHEDULE set day = "Fri" Where id = 1`,
So the table `MEETING` become

```
id | date        | time | schedule_id
1  | 10 Oct 2014 | 9:00 | 1
2  | 17 Oct 2014 | 9:00 | 1
3  | 24 Oct 2014 | 9:00 | 1
```

And also how can I handle if the day BEFORE edited is Friday and updated to Monday ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be (assuming 'date' and 'time' fields are varchar types) using `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE_FORMAT` functions. Then, on the following sql queries:

```
SET @schedule_id_to_modify = 1;

UPDATE MEETING SET date =DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d %b %Y')
                                     + INTERVAL 4 DAY,'%d %b %Y')
WHERE schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify;

UPDATE SCHEDULE SET day = DATE_FORMAT((
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d %b %Y')
  FROM MEETING where schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify LIMIT 1) ,'%a')
WHERE id = @schedule_id_to_modify;
```

just change the interval and the id to modify. E.g.,

change mon->fri :

```
SET @schedule_id_to_modify = 1;

UPDATE MEETING SET date =DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d %b %Y')
                                     + INTERVAL 4 DAY,'%d %b %Y')
WHERE schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify;

UPDATE SCHEDULE SET day = DATE_FORMAT((
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d %b %Y')
  FROM MEETING where schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify LIMIT 1) ,'%a')
WHERE id = @schedule_id_to_modify;
```

change fri->mon :

```
SET @schedule_id_to_modify = 1;

UPDATE MEETING SET date =DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d %b %Y')
                                     - INTERVAL 4 DAY,'%d %b %Y')
WHERE schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify;

UPDATE SCHEDULE SET day = DATE_FORMAT((
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d %b %Y')
  FROM MEETING where schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify LIMIT 1) ,'%a')
WHERE id = @schedule_id_to_modify;
```

SQL FIDDLE DEMO:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b7221/2

Note: These queries would be more simple if the types of `date` and `time` fields were defined as `Date` and `Time`... Then, the script would only be:

```
SET @schedule_id_to_modify = 1;

UPDATE MEETING SET date = date + INTERVAL 4 DAY
WHERE schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify;

UPDATE SCHEDULE SET day = DATE_FORMAT((
  SELECT date FROM MEETING where schedule_id = @schedule_id_to_modify
  LIMIT 1) ,'%a')
WHERE id = @schedule_id_to_modify;
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is exatctly what i need, its simple and understandable

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a trigger and if the day is always a forward day. Meaning if Mon is changed to Fri then the meeting dates will get changed to next Friday and so on.

For this I would create a table to store the day name and the numeric values something as

```
mysql> create table days (day varchar(10),day_number int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into days values ('Sun',0),('Mon',1),('Tue',2),('Wed',3),('Thu',4),('Fri',5),('Sat',6);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Next will create the following trigger which will trigger after update on the schedule

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger update_schedule after update on schedule
for each row
begin
 declare existing_day varchar(10);
 declare updated_day varchar(10);
 declare diff_day int;
 if new.day <> old.day then
  select day_number into existing_day from days where LOWER(day) = LOWER(old.day);
  select day_number into updated_day from days where LOWER(day) = LOWER(new.day);
  set diff_day = updated_day - existing_day ;
  if diff_day < 0 then
    set diff_day = diff_day * -1 ;
  end if ;
  update meeting set date = DATE_ADD(date , interval diff_day day) where schedule_id = new.id;
 end if;
end; //
delimiter ;
```

Now lets do some test

```
mysql> create table schedule (id int, room int, day varchar(100),class_id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into schedule values (1,11,'Mon',2),(2,12,'Tue',3),(5,11,'Mon',4);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table meeting (id int, date date, time time,schedule_id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into meeting values (1,'2014-10-06','9:00',1),(2,'2014-10-13','9:00',1),(3,'2014-10-20','9:00',1);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now lets update the schedule

```
mysql> update schedule set day = 'Fri' where id = 1 ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Now if we select the meeting data we should see the change as below -

```
mysql> select * from meeting ;
+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id   | date       | time     | schedule_id |
+------+------------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | 2014-10-10 | 09:00:00 |           1 |
|    2 | 2014-10-17 | 09:00:00 |           1 |
|    3 | 2014-10-24 | 09:00:00 |           1 |
+------+------------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```